# global $var não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, funções

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$_this =& get_instance();

function ConfiguracoesSistema($coluna){

    global $_this;

    $configuracoes = $_this->db->get('configuracao');

    if($configuracoes->num_rows() > 0){

        return $configuracoes->row()->$coluna;
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Preciso pegar a variável que está fora da função **$_this** e usa-lá dentro da função **ConfiguracoesSistema()**. O problema é que ela não está acessando, mesmo usando a palavra **global**. Caso eu coloque **$_this =& get_instance();** dentro da função, ele funciona. Meu PHP é versão 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Tente chama-lá dentro da função sem o "global":

```
<?php
$_this =& get_instance();

function ConfiguracoesSistema($coluna){

    $configuracoes = $_this->db->get('configuracao');

    if($configuracoes->num_rows() > 0){

        return $configuracoes->row()->$coluna;
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```